# What is the simplest way to calculate threshold in 1D 2-class classification?

Tags: classification, cart

Suppose I have points of two classes, distributed in 1D:

[image]

What is the simplest way to calculate a threshold to distinguish them?

May be just calculate two means for two classes and put threshold between them in the middle? Can I just calculate threshold in one run summing?

What is the name of this task?

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are looking for are measures of impurity. The exact same problem is solved in decision trees for each feature for an arbitrary number of classes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity

Specifically you chould have a look into gini impurity, misclassification rate and entropy. These measure can be used to identify the best threshold.

You will compute the impurity for each possible threshold (or a subset of all possible thresholds) and then chose the threshold with the lowest resulting impurity.

Answer (score 0):

there are many metrics for this.

Otsu's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method (there are implementations in sklearn)

Jenk's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization

You can also find local minima in a KDE...